# i want to filter my data with this from using visual studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to sort the data in the database with the date as the main condition with 2 date time picker 1 as the starting date and the other as the limit with this code by using between but I do not know the correct query form...[my from looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fg7h.png) the first DTP name is DTPDari and second DTPSampai

```
Call KONEKSI()
    CMD = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Pembayaran where tanggal_pembayaran BEETWEEN '" & DTPDari.Value & "'AND tanggal_pembayaran = '" & DTPSampai.Value & "'", CONN)
    DR = CMD.ExecuteReader
    DR.Read()`
```

Comment: I congratulate you on enabling user-driven polymorphism on your database.  It's a bold choice, but one I'm sure you will find rewarding.

Comment: Also.. what the heck is a `BEETWEEN` ?  A young beet?

Answer (score 0):

From the little what I understand from your question you can use any of the below

(syntax not tested)

```
SELECT * FROM Pembayaran where tanggal_pembayaran
WHERE        (tanggal_pembayaran BETWEEN '" & DTPDari.Value & "' AND '" & DTPSampai.Value & "')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Pembayaran where tanggal_pembayaran   
WHERE        (tanggal_pembayaran > '" & DTPDari.Value & "') and    (tanggal_pembayaran < '" & DTPSampai.Value & "')
```

Adding Function sample asper your request

```
Sub GetDetails()


        Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("NorthwindConnectionString").ConnectionString.ToString()
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

        Dim queryString2 = "SELECT       *
FROM            dbo.Customers
WHERE        (CreationDate BETWEEN @param1 AND @param2)"
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()

        cmd.CommandText = queryString2
        cmd.Connection = connection

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", from_DateTimePicker.Value.Date)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", to_DateTimePicker.Value.Date)
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader(0))
            'here fill on datatable Or anything you want
        End While

        connection.Close()

    End Sub
```

Comment: what the meaning for those 2 where?

Comment: i use option number 2 but its show an error data type mismatch?? field tanggal_pembayaran type is datetime..

Comment: nope i think it okay if i don't because its only 2 so should i use it?

Comment: yes.. try it..its working fine here .with same syntax on another table

Comment: what your code looks like? i never used parameter for select before

Comment: wait will give you a sample

Comment: You should always use parameters to protect your database. To accept an answer click the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. It is the best way to thank the one who answered.

Comment: These newbies misguide sometimes... :( However, as @Mary mentioned , use parameters …. or else you may fall victim to sql injection ...though it is not necessary until your app is developed in large scale